# Question about the .vscode-server directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

My root directory has 10G, and the /data directory has 700G. When I use vscode-remote, a .vscode-server folder is created in the /home/cx directory. With the increase of plug-ins, my root directory has no space. Some programs cannot be run. Can I change the location of the .vscode-server directory, or create the same directory under /data, and then create its Symbolic Link under /home/cx